# Native load error while using google maps V2 api

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-api-2

Below is the error i am getting on logCat

```
03-10 15:55:24.630: E/Icing(1371): Native load error: Native method not found:
com.google.android.gms.icing.impl.NativeIndex.nativeGetVersionCode:()I
 03-10 15:55:34.890: E/Icing(1371): Error initializing, resetting corpora: Could not    
create native index
03-10 15:55:34.900: E/Icing(1371): Internal init failed
03-10 15:55:34.900: E/Icing(1371): Couldn't handle android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED    
intent due to initialization failure.
```

I have followed all the steps in this [Maps V2 tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

because i am supporting min-sdk="8" I am using Google PLay services for Froyo , I have imported it as a library project and I am also referencing it in my project.

**The moment i add the following line in my manifest I start getting the above error** And this error occurs after the app has been installed on the emulator and when eclipse tries to start the main.activity. i am quite sure there is nothing wrong with the manifest because without importing the library and not using the following line the app works fine!

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

so there are two activities in my app MAIN and SEARCH.

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

>

    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />



    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="MY KEY"/>

 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/> 

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.travelpool.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

      <activity
        android:name="com.example.travelpool.Search"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.travelpool.Search" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

two different layouts one for MAIN and other for SEARCH. On click of a button on the main I start SEARCH and the search layout has the MAP FRAGMENT.But like i highlighted above the moment I import maps and Google play services i get the above error the Main activity loads up but when i click on the button which starts the Search activity the application crashes!
now again I would highlight that without importing maps library this activity works fine

i dont have the slightest idea as to what is going wrong can anyone please direct me or suggest me as to what all things should i check for?

Comment: Where is your map read permissions in your manifest.xml?

Comment: are you asking for application permissions? it has all the things specified in the tutorial here [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) like INTERNET,NETWORK_STATE, etc. Is this what you are asking? 

am confused what is map read permissions?